# Simple OO structure for a quiz app - minimising repitition - improving OO skills

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'm making a simple quiz application which has multiple questions. It has no back end and all of the interaction happens on one page.  my objects are laid out as follows -

```
q1Choices = {
    "question": "some question",
    "resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1": [2, 4, 6],
    "resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2": [1, 3, 5]
 };
 q2Choices = {
     "question": "another question",
     "resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1": [5, 6],
     "resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2": [1, 2, 3, 4]
 };
 q3Choices = {
     "question": "a third question",
     "resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1": [3, 4],
     "resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2": [1, 2]
 };
```

One question appears at a time, which has two possible answers  - when an answer is clicked another question appears and is populated from the corresponding object.

To allow for this, I have a counter variable and an array with the objects

```
var currentQuestion = 0;

var questionArray = [q1Choices, q2Choices, q3Choices];
```

I can see there is a lot of repetition in this code and was looking for a cleaner, more maintainable, more OO way of doing it.

Can anyone give me any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use arrays only?

```
questions = [
    [
        "some question", //question
        [2,4,6], //resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1
        [1, 3, 5] //resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2
    ],
    [
        "another question",
        [5, 6],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]
    ],
    ...
]
```

then, in `questions` items, you can access `question` key as index 0, `resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1` as index 1, `resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2` as index 2.

If you don't want to rely on meaningless numeric indexes declare constants and use them

```
resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1 = 1
questions[0][resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1]
```

---

More OO oriented sample:

```
function Questionary(){
    const question = 0
    const resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1 = 1
    const resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2 = 2
    this.questions = [
        [
            "some question",
            [2,4,6],
            [1, 3, 5]
        ],
        [
            "another question",
            [5, 6],
            [1, 2, 3, 4]
        ],
        ...
    ];
    this.currentQuestion = 0;
}

//method example
Questionary.prototype.skipQuestion = function() {
    return ++this.currentQuestion;
}
```

and you can go deeper adding a `Question` Object with `text`, `resultsToRemoveIfAnswer1`, `resultsToRemoveIfAnswer2` and so on...

Comment: That would mean less code, which is what I'm trying to achieve. But I don't feel it's a readable and it means I can't access the properties by name. Am I just being too fussy? Do you feel there's any benefit in being able to access the properties by name?

Comment: @user597264: you can access properties _by name_: use constants as I wrote. about readability just use a good indentation, I'll edit my post. About sticking on OOP I think it's exaggerated in this case having your code living in a single html page.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Regarding your comment on OOP, I agree that in a single page there's not much need to stick to it. I'm just using it as a learning exercise.

Comment: @user597264: I added a _more_ OO version (_more_ is also coding needed). You can learn a bit about javascript class declarations [here](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) (just a link, plenty of resources out there).